# how to tell if VM is running in server or client mode?

Tags: java

The Java hotspot vpm can be run with -client or -server argument. If neither is specified then it chooses one according to some rules.

Is it possible to tell whether a running VM is running in client or server mode when the mode is not specified on command line? I need this on a Windows box outside the running process.

I realize this is not a programming question, but I hope it is ok because it is programming related. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hemal hence my usage of `jinfo`, strictly limited to the `-flag` option: it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, you could check this with this code:

```
String s = System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
// s = Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
```

But this will be highly vendor specific.

From the command line, you could use [**jinfo**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jinfo.html) (used to [check a value of a given HotSpot VM option](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-jinfo-VM-Option-Value-Checker.html))

```
C:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\jps.exe" -l -m
21812 sun.tools.jps.Jps -l -m
19244 (eclipse)

C:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin\jinfo.exe" -flag NewRatio 19244
-XX:NewRatio=12
```

Since:

- it is rare to actually set the NewRatio [Hotpot option](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp) and
- the documentation specifies: Ratio of new/old generation sizes. `[x86 -server: 8; x86 -client: 12]`

12 means "Client".

Comment: I do need this on the command line, but unfortunately jinfo does not support this on Windows, which is where I need it.

Comment: the return string is vendor specific, but the whole Client vs Server VM issue is vendor specific as well.

Comment: @Hemal: if you can copy a JDK6, you can call jinfo on Windows

Comment: @VonC: I am using JDK6, but on Windows jinfo only supports the -flag option of a running process. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html#options

Comment: @Hemal hence my usage of jinfo, strictly limited to the -flag: it works

Answer (score 5):

Connect to the running Java process with [jvisualvm](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html). This will let you see the JVM arguments that have been used.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve this information connecting to the MBean server. If you are running a Sun VM, you have an MBean with name "java.lang:type=Runtime" which exposes the attribute "VmName", whose value is the same as system property "java.vm.name". In example, for a server vm the value will be something like "Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM". VM's from other vendors may use a similar mechanism.

You can connect to the MBean server either using the tools included in the JDK, like jconsole or jvisualvm, or by writing your own tool using [JMX](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jmx/index.html) if you need programmatic access.

Answer (score 0):

If the jvm is started with -debug, you can connect to it using jdb, and use eval  ...

```
eval System.getProperty("java.vm.name");
```

that or [jinfo](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jinfo.html)